# Ionic and Angular update for default template project

Tags: angularjs, npm, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and was a little bit lost while trying to install latest Ionic version.
According to the official site ionicframework.com : latest is 1.1.0 
But npm offers already 1.7.7 (www.npmjs.com/package/ionic).
While trying to create a sample project `ionic start myApp sidemenu` I could clone a repo with ionic 1.1.0 and angular 1.4.3.
And I already figured out how I could install ionic 1.7.7 globally using `npm install -g` . Also tried `ionic lib update` but all I get is 1.1.0 witch I already have installed with template project
So my questions are - why is versions differ from official to npm?
 And how to upgrade default project to latest ionic and Angular versions (1.4.9)?

Answer (score 0):

To install the latest release of any npm packages,
Open the package.json file and in the dependency version

eg. typescript: v1 use typescript: * is means the latest update.

```
{ "dependencies" : { "typescript" : "*" } }
```

and i think npm only gives the stable releases. if not explicitly required.

Comment: I just found out. NPM offers the latest version of the Ionic CLI 1.7.7, while the latest version of the library is still 1.1.0. And there is no any npm or bower package files for Ionic itself available...